# A question on wedge product of differential forms

Tags: differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be a $k$-form, is it true that
$$\omega\wedge\omega=0?$$
is it true that
$$d\omega\wedge d\omega=0?$$

Comment: Hint: the wedge/exterior product is anticommutative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Either** $\omega\wedge \omega=0$ **or** $d\omega\wedge d\omega=0$, because firstly, the exterior product is graded anticommutative: $\alpha\wedge\beta=(-1)^{|\alpha||\beta|}\beta\wedge\alpha$, where
$|\alpha|$ denotes the degree of $\alpha$. It is 0 for odd-degree forms. And secondly, the exterior derivative increments the degree.

Answer (score 5):

No. For example, over $\mathbb{R}^4$, the $1$-form $\omega = x\; dy + z\; dw$ has $\omega\wedge \omega = 0$ (as any $1$-form has by (graded)-commutativity), but $d\omega = dx\wedge dy + dz \wedge dw$ has
$$d\omega \wedge d\omega = 2\; dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\wedge dw\not =0.$$

Comment: If $a=a_idx^i$ is a $1$-form, then $a\wedge a=0$, is $a\wedge da=0?$

Comment: No. Take $a = x\; dy + dz$.